# Arduino IR receiver doesn't work after pressed a button

Tags: arduino, infrared

I'm trying to make a simple program that can receive IR codes and at the same time send another IR code when I press on a button.

My problem is: The IR receiver only works before I pressed a button. If I press the button, the "first if-line" doesn't work anymore.

```cpp
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend;

int RECV_PIN = 2;   //Transmitter pin (input)
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);  //TP-stuff
decode_results results;   //TP-stuff


void setup() {
  pinMode(9, INPUT);  //knapp 6, LEDIG
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);  //IRSEND
  pinMode(2, INPUT); //tramsmititer pin
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver //TP
}

void loop() {

  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {                   //Transmitter IR
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);           //Transmitter IR

    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value    //Transmitter IR


  } else if (digitalRead(9) == LOW) {
    irsend.sendNEC(0x20DF8679, 32); //LEDIG
    Serial.println("LEDIG knapp");
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delay(400);

  }
}
```

Comment: Someone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Enable again the IR receiver after you send and IR message:

```
else if (digitalRead(9) == LOW) {
    irsend.sendNEC(0x20DF8679, 32); //LEDIG
    Serial.println("LEDIG knapp");
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    delay(400);
    irrecv.enableIRIn();
}
```